# Repeat a whole row N times based on a cell value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I'm using Google Sheet and I am kind of new at it so I want to split test Column and repeating other columns in each row.

Before Splitting

```
FILE NUMBER || NUMBER OF TESTS ||   TEST            || SUBMETTIED ON
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2121122     ||    3            || CBC,URINE,Blood roup  || 2022-01-31 23:27
```

Wishing Result After Splitting :

```
2121122     ||    3            || CBC                   || 2022-01-31 23:27
2121122     ||    3            || URINE                 || 2022-01-31 23:27
2121122     ||    3            || Blood Group           || 2022-01-31 23:27
```

I want to split test Column and repeating other columns in each row:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=index(split(A2&"❄️"&B2&"❄️"&transpose(split(C2,", ",0))&"❄️"&D2,"❄️"))
```

[image]